# fetch the value of data-attribute based on active class

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

i want to fetch the value of data-attribute `data-itemtype` based on 
 `ul > li class = "activeTab"`

here is my code.

```
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-itemtype="1" class="activeTab"><a href="#tab1">Published</a></li>
    <li data-itemtype="0" class=""><a href="#tab2">Unpublished</a></li>
</ul>
```

if `class="activeTab"` is in first `<li>` element then fetch the data attribute of first li element i.e 1 in this case and hence same applies for the second or any number of li elements.

i tried this

```
var itemType = $('ul.tabs').find('li.activeTab').attr('data-itemtype');
```

and it does not work. it shows value undefined.

**Update:**

i am using tabs. i want to know which tab is currently active and i need that value in javascript variable.

here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="widget">
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li data-itemtype="1"><a href="#tab1">Published</a></li>
        <li data-itemtype="0"><a href="#tab2">Unpublished</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">
            <div class="widget" style="margin-top:0px;">
                <div class="title"><img src="/images/icons/dark/cart3.png" alt="" class="titleIcon" /><h6>Published Items</h6></div>                          
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content"> 
            <div class="widget" style="margin-top:0px;">
                <div class="title"><img src="/images/icons/dark/cart3.png" alt="" class="titleIcon" /><h6>Unpublished Items</h6></div>
                <p>Content</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="clear"></div>        
</div>
```

the jQuery being used is this.

```
$.fn.contentTabs = function(){ 

        $(this).find(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all content
        $(this).find("ul.tabs li:first").addClass("activeTab").show(); //Activate first tab
        $(this).find(".tab_content:first").show(); //Show first tab content

        $("ul.tabs li").click(function() {
            $(this).parent().parent().find("ul.tabs li").removeClass("activeTab"); //Remove any "active" class
            $(this).addClass("activeTab"); //Add "active" class to selected tab
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".tab_content").hide(); //Hide all tab content
            var activeTab = $(this).find("a").attr("href"); //Find the rel attribute value to identify the active tab + content
            $(activeTab).show(); //Fade in the active content
            return false;
        });

    };
    $("div[class^='widget']").contentTabs(); //Run function on any div with class name of "Content Tabs"
```

the above code does not work for me.

Comment: [Yes, it does](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3H5nc/).

Comment: @David Thomas not sure, but it does not work for me. i have update my question with some more details.

Comment: Does the JS Fiddle demo I linked to work for you, though?

Comment: nope it says `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar what browser are you using?

Comment: I don't know where you wanted to retrieve the attribute, so I added a `click` handler in a [demo I made, of what you've posted](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3H5nc/1/). And, again, this *seems* to work. (Chrome 18/Win XP)

Comment: it works inside of the click handler. i was trying it outside. anyhow i want to use it inside the click handler. thank you. it works now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be working fine.

I would use `.data(...)` instead:

```
var itemType = $('ul.tabs').find('li.activeTab').data('itemtype');
alert(itemType);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/2GYxh/

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar can you please show ***exactly*** what you were doing?

Comment: i don't know why. but it works inside of the click handler. and if i place the code outside it does not work not sure why.