# JQuery - fetch value data-attribute when active class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to display the **data-attribute** when an `anchor` tag has an active class in my console.log

unfortunately, It always outputs a `null` value.

I referred to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247247/fetch-the-value-of-data-attribute-based-on-active-class)

here is my **HTML**:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {

    var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
    previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
    $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item

    var itemType = $('.list-group a').find('.active').data('itemtype');

    console.log(itemType);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="1">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="3">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="4">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="2">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

please help me to be on track with the development.

Thank you in advance

Comment: are you trying to add `active` class on the element you just clicked? and remove other with `active` class?

Comment: As you have added `active` class in previous statement. Direct use `$(e.target).data('itemtype');`, As per you HTML you can use `this` inplace of `e.target`.

Comment: I am trying to output the data-itemtype if an anchor tag as an active class.

Comment: Just use $('.list-group') instead of $('.list-group a'). That is because $('.list-group a') is already pointing to the anchor tag and adding a find to it is performing another search of an element that has an active attribute under the anchor tag.

Comment: yeah. thank you for that! @NeilVillareal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such finding `"active"` class in the div having class `list-group` so use `$('.list-group').find('.active').data('itemtype')` selector in place of `$('.list-group a').find('.active').data('itemtype')`.

Your selector `$('.list-group a').find('.active').data('itemtype')` will try to find `active` class in the `a` tag of div with class `list-group` which is making issue.

Please check working snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {

    var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
    previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
    $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item

    var itemType = $('.list-group').find('.active').data('itemtype');

    console.log(itemType);

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="1">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="3">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="4">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="2">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this one  

$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {

        var previous = $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active");
        previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
        $(e.target).addClass('active'); // activated list-item

        var itemType = $('.list-group a').find('.active').attr('data-itemtype');

        console.log(itemType);

    });

});
```

Comment: this outputs an undefined data

Answer (score 1):

Your code didn't worked as the `anchor` has no child/descendant elements when using statement `$('.list-group a').find('.active')` thus you are getting `undefined`, Here you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
  var itemtype = $('.list-group a').filter('.active').data('itemtype');
```

As you have added `active` class in previous statement. Direct use `$(e.target).data('itemtype');`,

As per HTML you can also use `this` instead of `e.target`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function(e) {

    //Remove active class from siblings 
    $(this).closest(".list-group").children(".active").removeClass('active')

    // activated list-item
    $(this).addClass('active');
    var itemType = $(this).data('itemtype');

    console.log(itemType);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="1">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="3">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="4">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="2">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this should help you

```
var itemtype=$(".list-group a.active").attr('data-itemtype')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of the `$('.list-group-item').on('click')` event

```
$('.list-group-item').on('click', function (e) {
  var previous = $(".list-group-item");
  previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
  $(this).addClass('active'); // activated list-item

  var itemType = $('.list-group a.active').attr('data-itemtype');
  console.log($(itemType);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

@Terence, It always outputs a `null` value, because the `find` function gets the descendant elements.

This code `var itemType = $('.list-group a').find('.active').data('itemtype');` returns `null` because there are no descendants inside the `anchor` that have a class called `active`

You can do it in the following way to get the `data-attribute` you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.list-group-item').on('click', function(event) {
    var previous = $('.list-group-item.active');
    previous.removeClass('active'); // previous list-item
    $(this).addClass('active'); // activated list-item
    var itemType = $(this).data('itemtype');
    console.clear();
    console.log(itemType);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group">
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="1">Cras justo odio</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="0">Dapibus ac facilisis in</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="3">Morbi leo risus</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="4">Porta ac consectetur ac</a>
  <a href="#" class="list-group-item" data-itemtype="2">Vestibulum at eros</a>
</div>
```